# Password matching in AngularJS using the $validators pipeline produces unexpected results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vBK9A/).

Using the $validators pipeline, I am trying to check that a field contains the same value as another field.

Each input in this example is associated with the other, such that the expected result is as follows:

- Enter a value in input#1
- Enter same value in input#2
- Both fields should now be valid
- Alter the value in input#1
- input#1 should be invalid (or input#2 or both)

Initially, I did this using a `$watch` on both the current model and the target to be equal to, so only one of the two fields needed to use the directive. However, with the introduction of the `$validators` pipeline, this method stopped working unexpectedly (maybe a bug).

Anyhow, as you can see, when the second input is altered, the value is receives for the associated input is `undefined`.

## Solution

I solved this by the following:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3A5v/)

As Nikos said, the two instances were cancelling each other out, so this was fixed by the following code:

```
$scope.$watch('passwordWatch', function(pass) {
    $control.$validate();
});
```

So now, when the target input changes, the current input revalidates. When the current input changes, it validates automatically (as usual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that when a validator fails (returns `false`), then the underlying model value is set to `undefined`. So:

1. You type something in the password, say `"aaa"`; this is *NOT* the same as `passwordConfirm`, so the validator returns `false` and the model gets the `undefined` value
2. You type the same value in passwordConfirm; but from above the value of the password is `undefined` and `undefined !== "aaa"`, so the passwordConfirm validator returns `false` too.
3. And so on...

Comment: haha i completely overlooked that. the documentation on the $validators pipeline is lacking currently so i was unaware it did that.

any suggestion as to how this should be done then?

Comment: :) Actually I tried tweaking the fiddle, but it seems a bit more complex than just tweaking *or* I am doing something wrong. Hopefully I will get back to this later. What I am trying to do is use the classic `$parsers`/`$formatters` instead of the `$validators`. The `$parsers`/`$formatters` allow you to return a value, even if the input is invalid, so the model can still (?) be updated and then the next check potentially succeed.

Comment: check out my edit in the main question. i got it working currently by only listening on one of the two inputs and revalidating when the target changes.