# Angularjs setValidity causing modelValue to not update

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I'm having some basic trouble with a form. Here's what I did.

I snagged this cool looking directive from here: https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-input-match

It looks like this:

```
directive('match', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        match: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return (ngModel.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ngModel.$modelValue)) || scope.match === ngModel.$viewValue;
        }, function(currentValue, previousValue) {
          ngModel.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Essentially, this directive watches the element it is attached to's model value, and compares it to the model value in the match attribute.

So...for example, below we're watching to see if both passwords match:

```
Password: <input ng-model="password" type="password" />
Confirm: <input ng-model="passwordConfirm" type="password" match="password" />
```

The directive seems to be working, in that it sets ng-valid-match and ng-invalid-match appropriately.

However, once it is set to invalid, the passwordConfirm model never gets updated again. I've done a ton of console.loggin, looking at ngModel in the directive, and here is what it looks like when both passwords match:

```
Constructor {$viewValue: "asdf", $modelValue: undefined, $validators: Object, $parsers: Array[0], $formatters: Array[0]…}
$$debounceViewValueCommit: function (trigger, revalidate) {
$$invalidModelValue: "asdf"
$$lastCommittedViewValue: "asdf"
$$runValidators: function (modelValue, viewValue) {
$$validityState: ValidityState
$$writeModelToScope: function () {
$commitViewValue: function (revalidate) {
$dirty: true
$error: Object
$formatters: Array[0]
$invalid: false
$isEmpty: function (value) {
$modelValue: undefined
$name: "passwordConfirmation"
$parsers: Array[0]
$pristine: false
$render: function () {
$rollbackViewValue: function () {
$setPristine: function () {
$setTouched: function () {
$setUntouched: function () {
$setValidity: function (validationErrorKey, isValid) {
$setViewValue: function (value, trigger, revalidate) {
$touched: true
$untouched: false
$valid: true
$validate: function () {
$validators: Object
$viewChangeListeners: Array[0]
$viewValue: "asdf"
__proto__: Object
```

Note that the $viewValue is correct, but the $modelValue is listed as undefined and $invalidModelValue still has a value.

Here's what the html looks like, again when both passwords match:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-required ng-valid ng-valid-match ng-touched" id="passwordConfirmation" name="passwordConfirmation" placeholder="Confirm your password" ng-model="passwordConfirmation" required="" match="password" style="">
```

Am I missing something somewhere? I've been running in circles for hours.

Comment: As long as value is invalid the model returns undefined, when it match the criteria then model is updated

Comment: Right, but the form element is getting set to valid, so I would expect the model value to get updated appropriately.

Comment: There was a breaking change to the way the `$modelValue` is set.  If the model is invalid it will set the value to `$$invalidModelValue` https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f3cb2741161353f387d02725637ce4ba062a9bc0

Comment: Suggest you answer the question yourself and accept the answer instead of providing a solution at the end of the question.

Comment: suggest to put this as an answer, helped me as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like maybe using $setValidity is not the way to go here. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385104/password-matching-in-angularjs-using-the-validators-pipeline-produces-unexpecte) that proposes a different solution, using $validators and $validate(), and this is working for me great. The new code looks like this:

```
directive('match', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      match: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch('match', function(pass){
        ngModel.$validate();
      });
      ngModel.$validators.match = function(modelValue, viewValue){
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;
        var match = scope.match;
        return value === match;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 6):

In a [recent update](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f3cb2741161353f387d02725637ce4ba062a9bc0), a change was made to the way the `$modelValue` is populated based on the validity of the field.  If the field is invalid, the `$modelValue` will be set to `undefined` and a new attribute, `$$invalidModelValue` will be populated with the value.

As a solution to work with 1.2.* and 1.3.* I have come up with this:

```
 .directive('match', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            match: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(function() {
                modelValue = ctrl.$modelValue || ctrl.$$invalidModelValue;
                return (ctrl.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(modelValue)) || scope.match === modelValue;
            }, function(currentValue) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oaEZRUwejRVoXRKCwq7g?p=preview)

While this solution works with both version, 1.3.* has the new `$validators` pipeline which is recommended for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Might be related to the fact that you are using

```
scope: { 
     match : "=" 
}
```

That create an isolated scope for your directive and doesn't herite from the parent scope where your ngModel is.

I suggest trying to remove that scope part of your directive and access it from attributes instead.

It will become something like :

```
directive('match', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.match = attrs.match;
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return (ngModel.$pristine && angular.isUndefined(ngModel.$modelValue)) || scope.match === ngModel.$viewValue;
        }, function(currentValue, previousValue) {
          ngModel.$setValidity('match', currentValue);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, as attrs.match isn't the value of 'password', it's actually just the string 'password' itself. When I leave that scope declaration in there, scope.match is equal to the model value of password, so that does seem to be working.

Comment: Did you try scope.$eval(attrs.match) ?