# Making dropdown directive in Angular required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have written my first directive in Angular, which is a dropdown, here is the template :

```
<select class='form-control' ng-model='vm.scope.fixtureToBeUpdated.awayTeam' ng-options='awayTeam.teamName for awayTeam in vm.scope.awayTeams track by awayTeam.teamId' required>
    <option style='display: none' value=''>{{'SELECT' | translate }}</option>
</select>
```

Here is where it is defined in the controller :

```
function awayTeamsDropdown() {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: true,
            controller: "fixturesController",
            templateUrl: "/views/awayteamsDropdown.html"
        };
    }
```

And here is the form that it is used in :

```
<form novalidate id="AddUpdateFixture" name="AddUpdateFixture" ng-submit="vm.addUpdateFixture()">

                        <!--addFixture or updateFixture-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" ng-model="vm.scope.fixtureToBeUpdated.fixtureId"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tournament">{{ 'TOURNAMENT' | translate }}</label>
                            <tournaments-dropdown></tournaments-dropdown>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="week">{{ 'WEEK' | translate }}</label>
                            <weeks-dropdown></weeks-dropdown>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="awayTeamName">{{ 'AWAY_TEAM' | translate }}</label>
                            <awayteams-dropdown></awayteams-dropdown>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="awayTeamScore">{{ 'POINTS' | translate }}</label>
                            <input id="awayTeamScore" type="text" class="form-control" name="awayTeamScore"
                                   ng-model="vm.scope.fixtureToBeUpdated.awayTeamScore" ng-min="0" ng-max="77" />
                            <span ng-show="AddUpdateFixture.awayTeamScore.$dirty && AddUpdateFixture.awayTeamScore.$error.min" class="text-warning">{{ 'SCORE_MIN' | translate }}</span>
                            <span ng-show="AddUpdateFixture.awayTeamScore.$dirty && AddUpdateFixture.awayTeamScore.$error.max" class="text-warning">{{ 'SCORE_MAX' | translate }}</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="AddUpdateFixture.$invalid" class="button bg-darkBlue bg-active-darkBlue fg-white">{{ 'SAVE' | translate }}</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

But in the button in the form ng-disabled is set to false even if an item is not selected from the dropdown.  How do I make ng-disabled set to true if nothing is selected in the dropdown?

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27501281/548997) it looks like you will have to write some code to set the validation properties manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [required on custom directive select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500913/required-on-custom-directive-select)

Comment: Any pointers on how I could apply that example in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this

```html
 <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="vm.scope.fixtureToBeUpdated.awayTeam === undefined" class="button bg-darkBlue bg-active-darkBlue fg-white">{{ 'SAVE' | translate }}</button>
 </div>
```

Or

```
ng-disabled="!vm.scope.fixtureToBeUpdated.awayTeam"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of other fields (both directives and not) with different validations that will also determine the value of ng-disabled, so this approach could get very complicated as each of these field validations would need to be included in the same way

Comment: Ah, because your Qs then it's not clear, "How do I make ng-disabled set to true if nothing is selected in the dropdown(and you provided one of the dropdowns)" while you seem to have multiple dropdowns

Comment: To solve this then to each dropdown add the first <option value="">Select something</option> to be empty value so require will work.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `ng-required`:

```
<select class='form-control' ng-model='vm.scope.fixtureToBeUpdated.awayTeam' ng-options='awayTeam.teamName for awayTeam in vm.scope.awayTeams track by awayTeam.teamId' ng-required="vm.scope.fixtureToBeUpdated.awayTeam">
    <option style='display: none' value=''>{{'SELECT' | translate }}</option>
</select>
```