# angularjs directive to check password has been repeated not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Trying to make an AngularJS directive work, I'm following this tutorial: http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/

In a Signup form, the directive called repeat-password, checks if the two emails input in a form correspond:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success' : signupForm.confirmPassword.$valid && signupForm.confirmPassword.$dirty, 'has-error' : signupForm.confirmPassword.$invalid && signupForm.confirmPassword.$dirty }">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="password" name="confirmPassword" ng-model="confirmPassword" repeat-password="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>

    <div class="help-block text-danger my-special-animation" ng-if="signupForm.confirmPassword.$dirty"ng-messages="signupForm.confirmPassword.$error">
       <div ng-message="required">You must confirm password.</div>
       <div ng-message="repeat">Passwords do not match.</div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <button type="submit" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Create Account</button>
```

The required part of the html works but not the repeat-password part, no error message is showing, it doesn't prevent me from submitting the form and I'm directly routed to where the submit button leads too.
The code that I'm using for directive itself is the following:

```
angular.module("MyApp")
    .directive("repeatPassword", function () {
        return {
            require: "ngModel",
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                var otherInput = elem.inheritedData("$formController")[attrs.repeatPassword];
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                    if (value === otherInput.$viewValue) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity("repeat", true);
                        return value;
                    }
                    ctrl.$setValidity("repeat", false);
                });
                otherInput.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("repeat", value === ctrl.$viewValue);
                    return value;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

I don't know if it's useful but I'm using AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.15 and Angular-ui.router 0.2.10.

Comment: Have you tested the solution I provided? If it works for you please accept the answer to 'close' your question. If your issue is not solved, let me know how I can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generic version of a fieldMatch directive with comments and references to other SO questions. It has been tested with both 1.2 and 1.3-beta.

```
.directive('fieldMatch', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            var checkFieldMatch = function () {
                // WARNING - FIXME:
                // when a validator fails (returns false), then the underlying model value is set to undefined
                //
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692775
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385104
                //
                // => solution: use ngModel.$viewValue instead of ngModel.$modelValue

                var fieldMatch = scope.$eval(attrs.dsFieldMatch),
                    value = ngModel.$modelValue || ngModel.$viewValue;

                // If fieldMatch or ngModel.$viewValue is defined,
                // they should match
                if (fieldMatch || value) {
                    return fieldMatch === value;
                }
                return true;
            };

            scope.$watch(checkFieldMatch, function (n) {
                //set the form control to valid if both
                //passwords are the same, else invalid
                ngModel.$setValidity('fieldMatch', n);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

See these 2 other questions:

[Angularjs setValidity causing modelValue to not update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692775)

[Password matching in AngularJS using the $validators pipeline produces unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385104)